# Find pixel offset for active plot area

Tags: python, matplotlib

I saved multiple matrix images using

```
imshow
savefig
```

to disk and now I would like to detect the offset between the picture frame and the first pixel.
My problem is that I have to use labels around the plot area which moves the real data view around based on the label text length -> offsets become arbitrary.
Hence, I would like to automatically detect the offset between the upper left corner in the image and the upper left corner of the active plot area + the width & height used to plot one matrix entry.

I guess the parameter must be somewhere buried in the

```
axes.transData
axes.transAxes
```

properties (?), but I seem not to find it.
Thanks,
EL

Comment: Can you use ax.get_position() to get the location and size of the axes?